# SQL Merge two queries and insert a new column for calculus

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables, `Transactions` (attributes of Interest: disponent_id, transaction_id) and `Attachments` (attributes of Interest: disponent_id, filename).

The main goal is the following:

I want to group the transactions per each Disponent of the table "Transact" (transactions per disponent)

1. The same with the table "Attach" (attachments per disponent)
2. After, I want to merge both and insert a new column, which shows the ratio of attachments per transaction (Attachments/Transactions)
3. ..

```
(1)
Disponent | Transactions
213456    | 35
...

(2)
Disponent | Attachments
213456    | 70

(3)
Disponent | Transactions | Attachments | Ratio
213456    | 35           | 70          | 2
...
```

I've tried

```
SELECT Transact.disponent_id, COUNT(Transact.transaction_id) AS Transactionnumber
FROM Transact
GROUP BY Transact.disponent_id
UNION ALL
SELECT Attach.disponent_id, COUNT(Attach.filename) AS Filenumber
FROM Attach
GROUP BY Attach.disponent_id
```

But the result is only:

```
disponent_id | transactionnumber
234576 | 65
...
```

How can I insert the calculation and the attachment column?

Comment: Break it down into the 2 SELECT statements and see what you get from each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used your queries within `with` clause, then used new select statement with inner join.

check it out:

```
With wth0 as 
(
    SELECT 
      Transact.disponent_id, 
      COUNT(Transact.transaction_id) AS Transactionnumber
    FROM Transact
    GROUP BY Transact.disponent_id
), 
wth1 as 
(
    SELECT Attach.disponent_id, COUNT(Attach.filename) AS Filenumber
    FROM Attach
    GROUP BY Attach.disponent_id
)
SELECT 
  wth0.disponent_id,
  wth0.Transactionnumber,
  wth1.Filenumber,
  wth1.Filenumber / wth0.Transactionnumber as Ratio
from wth0
inner join wth1 
  on wth0.disponent_id = wth1.disponent_id;
```

Comment: ohhhhh it works wonderful, a kind of magic :D is it possible to show the ratio with decimal values? 1/5 is currently 0. What to do, if I want 0.2?

Comment: If you believe this answer is helpful for you, please consider to mark it as answer

Comment: @joePerchi if you convert at least of Filenumber of Transactionnumber to a non-integer value you should get a non-integer result from division. E.g. replace wth1.Filenumber / wth0.Transactionnumber with wth1.Filenumber::float / wth0.Transactionnumber

Comment: `wth1.Filenumber / wth0.Transactionnumber / 1.0` will do the trick